# Python: How to print a list without quotations and square brackets

Tags: python

I am trying to print this python `list` as in the format `value1`, `value1`, `value3`.

But what I get is something like this:

```
['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
```

So I want to get rid of `'` and `[]`.

This is what I tried, but it now prints the result without **only brackets**:

```py
tagList = []
count = 0
for i in range(20):
    try:
        if not response['TagList'][i]['Key']:
            print("Tags not found")
        else:
            if str(response['TagList'][i]['Key']) == "t_AppID":
                pass
            tagList.append(str(response['TagList'][i]['Key']))
    except:
        pass

return str(tagList)[1:-1]
```

Comment: Did you expect otherwise? You only remove the first and last characters, i.e. the brackets. Maybe `", ".join(tagList)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `join` function on `str`:

```
>>> mylist = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
>>> print(mylist)
['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
>>> print(', '.join(mylist))
value1, value2, value3
```

Comment: how can I return this value?

Comment: `return ', '.join(mylist)`?

Answer (score 0):

To return list elements as a string you can use something like:

```
def as_string(values):
    return ', '.join(values)

print(as_string(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

#### Output:

```
a, b, c
```

Comment: how can I return this value?

Comment: @JananathBanuka - Updated to return the values.